# Errors when sending GZIPed data in POST to node.js server

Tags: node.js, post, gzip

My Node.js server need to receive large amounts of compressed JSON (gzip) data in POST requests. I've added some code to `gunzip` the payload of the POST, but the outcome is always incorrect and varies depending on the size of the JSON posted.

```
var http = require('http');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var port = process.env.port || 1337;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        if( req.headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip' ) {
            var body = [];

            req.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('Receiving data...');
                body.push(data);
            });

            req.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Data received! Uncompressing...');

                var buffer = Buffer.concat(body);
                zlib.gunzip(buffer, function(err, result) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('Unzipped!!')
                        var r = result.toString();
                        console.log(r)
                        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                        res.end(r);
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                        res.end('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                });              
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Everything OK with uncompressed requests!');
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end('Some JSON was received!\n');
        }

        req.on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end('Something went wrong!');
        });
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Hello World\n');        
    }
}).listen(1337);
```

If I send normal, uncompressed JSON data everything works.

The result with compression:

<strike>`{"id":1, "name":"Gabe"}` -> returns 500 with Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' when trying to uncompress the data.</strike> As pointed out in a comment, this is not incorrect behavior, as the payload is so small that is not compressed.

`{"id":1,"name":"Gabe","age":33,"address":"555 Road, City, Province","occupation":"I exchange code for money"}` -> the request ends abruptly with a 504 just after the `request.on('data'...`, although the process continues and shows the correct uncompressed data, as seen below.

`{"id":1,"name":"Gabe","age":666,"address":"666 Road, City, Province","occupation":"I sleep during the day and write code at night... not"}` -> It's stuck receiving the data and does nothing more.

[image: 504 after data received - process continues and shows correct payload]

To test, I've configured Fiddler to send compressed data whenever the Content-Encoding header is set with [Rules -> Customize Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733613/987824):

```
if (oSession.requestBodyBytes != null && oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length>50 && oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Content-Encoding")){
    oSession.requestBodyBytes = Utilities.GzipCompress(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
    oSession["Content-Length"] = oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length.ToString();
    oSession["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
}
```

A sample request:

```
POST http://localhost:1337/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Encoding: gzip
Host: localhost:1337

{"id":1,"name":"Gabe","age":00,"address":"555 Road, City, Province","occupation":"I exchange code for money"}
```

I tried listening to errors and using Domains, but I don't see any error generated. I've also tried with Express both doing it manually and using the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions) module which supports GZIP and Deflate and the behavior is the same. Tested with Node 0.10.18 and 0.10.30, without Express and finally with Express 3 and 4.

So, what going on here? Am I so incredibly blind that I'm missing a colon somewhere? Is this a bug in Node? Is it the way I'm sending the request with Fiddler?

Comment: The sample request you posted at the end doesn't look like it has `gzip`d data in it; that looks like it's still plain JSON. Are you just showing what the uncompressed JSON should be, or is that really what Fiddler is sending to node?

Comment: @MikeS. Fiddler takes care of gziping the JSON with the addition to its Rules. If you look at the screen capture, the Raw request shows just a bunch of characters, which are the compressed payload.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Ok, just double-checking :)

Comment: In the example you gave {"id":1, "name":"Gabe"} should not be compressed as it is less than 50 bytes for which you check it in fiddler. Can you check how is that throwing Z_DATA_ERROR ?

Comment: @user568109 The reason it's throwing is because, as you say, it's not compressed and the code sample tries to unzip it anyways because I send the request with the Content-Encoding header. I think that example is misleading, I might as well remove it. Thanks for the observation!